# Android: Why calendar event's changes their id after editing (not always, sometimes)?

Tags: android, google-calendar-api

I need to set some action on event (custom reminder) and I am using event's id to remember it. However, problem is that after editing event a few times it (randomly) changes its event id. It can be reproduced any time on any device (I tried 6 different ones) by following these steps:

1. Create event
2. Edit event until it changes id (usually it requires only 2-3 edits,
   sometimes more but usually not more than 7-8, maximum was like 15
   edits or so)

Why does this happen? I really need to remember event id (my app need to set custom reminder on this event) but if event's id changes, it is useless for me.

Comment: Could you show me your source code which changes event's properties? Which method do you use: patch or update?

Comment: Hi, I have no code to editing event. Maybe I wrote it not so clear but I am creating and editing events directly in calendar application. Whole problem is, that when you create some event in calendar (I am using default google calendar app) and you edit it few times, event's id just changes randomly...

Comment: Sorry, but I do not know what is a "default google calendar app". Could you give me an example URL where I can see this app and read about it? Event does not change id during the update process.

Comment: it is default google calendar from google :) Here: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.calendar

Comment: Yes, I tried it and it works for me. Are you sure that you always change the same event?

Comment: surely. How did you check, that event id was not changed? I did just this: 1) create new event in calendar app 2) edit it. Sooner or later it will change event's id (I am logging events id in my app, so I can clearly see it changes after few edits - sometimes after 1st edit, sometimes after 6th edit etc.)

Comment: I was using: Events.list method https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list#examples and Events.get https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/get#examples method to check what I have in my calendar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, I found out, that when you edit some event, android doesn't actually edit the event - it deletes it, and recreate a new one (with changes) lol.

Usually the newly created event has the same id as the previous one, but not always.

Jeez Google, seriously?